# Android Universal Music Player how its work

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer, android-music-player, exoplayer

I am curious about google sample github respository https://github.com/googlesamples/android-UniversalMusicPlayer android universal music player are not using MediaPlayer or ExoPlayer to stream audio file from url. **What exact method that they use in the sample project?**

Comment: Your question is vague. Did you not open the project and find out? The answer IS the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They do indeed use `MediaPlayer` as seen in the [LocalPlayback class](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-UniversalMusicPlayer/blob/master/mobile/src/main/java/com/example/android/uamp/playback/LocalPlayback.java)

Comment: thanks...in that project how they buffering the audio so fast? I create media player on my own but the buffering time is quite long, so i switch to exoplayer